# iOS - Silent Notification Not Working Under Production Environment

Tags: ios, notifications, production, silent

Everything worked just fine a little earlier before. But suddenly I cannot receive silent notifications from Parse. I've then tested under development environment and again it worked well. But when I switched back to production environment, it failed again.

P.S. I can receive remote notification from Parse under production environment, but not silent notification. The delegate isn't even called.

Comment: did you setting your notification send-box to production? did yo change your Dev .cer to Production .cer in parse end?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure I did that.